# Error in Photoshop Script?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Hi I have a photoshop script for creating permutations of layers. So far I have my PSD document saved to the desktop.

The photoshop file consists of the 8 Layers

```
    <Layer 1>
    <Layer 2>
    <Layer 3>
    <Layer 4>
    <Layer 5>
    <Layer 6>
    <Layer 7>
    <Layer 8>
```

Named like exactly like above

The script is throwing an error :

Error 1302: No Such Element
Line: 22
->   app.activeDocument.artLayers[t-i].visible = false;

```
#target photoshop

//set pathToSave to C:\ or whatever - make sure it has a \\ (or / on Mac/Linux) on the end
//if you're on windows, every \ needs to be \\ instead
var pathToSave = "C:\\temp\\"; 

var a = 1; // number base layers
var p = 8; // number of layers used for permutations 

main();

 function main() {
     var exportInfo = new Object();
        initExportInfo(exportInfo);

var t = app.activeDocument.artLayers.length-1; 

function hideAll() 
{
    for (var i = a; i < a+p; i++) 
    {
        app.activeDocument.artLayers[t-i].visible = false;
    }
}

for (var x = a; x < a+p; x++) {
    for (var y = x+1; y < a+p; y++) {
        for (var z = y+1; z < a+p; z++) {
            hideAll();
            app.activeDocument.artLayers[t-x].visible = true;
            app.activeDocument.artLayers[t-y].visible = true;
            app.activeDocument.artLayers[t-z].visible = true;
            saveFile( app.activeDocument, x+'-'+y+'-'+z, exportInfo);
             }
         }  
    }
}

    function initExportInfo(exportInfo)
{
     exportInfo.destination = new String("");
     exportInfo.fileNamePrefix = new String("untitled_");
     exportInfo.selectionOnly = false;
     exportInfo.fileType = 'jpeg';
     exportInfo.icc = true;
     exportInfo.jpegQuality = 8;
     exportInfo.psdMaxComp = true;
     exportInfo.tiffCompression = TIFFEncoding.NONE;
     exportInfo.tiffJpegQuality = 8;
     exportInfo.pdfEncoding = PDFEncoding.JPEG;
     exportInfo.pdfJpegQuality = 8;
     exportInfo.targaDepth = TargaBitsPerPixels.TWENTYFOUR;
     exportInfo.bmpDepth = BMPDepthType.TWENTYFOUR;
     exportInfo.png24Transparency = true;
     exportInfo.png24Interlaced = false;
     exportInfo.png8Transparency = true;
     exportInfo.png8Interlaced = false;

     try {
    exportInfo.destination = Folder(app.activeDocument.fullName.parent).fsName; // destination folder
    var tmp = app.activeDocument.fullName.name;
    exportInfo.fileNamePrefix = decodeURI(tmp.substring(0, tmp.indexOf("."))); // filename body part
} catch(someError) {
    exportInfo.destination = new String("");
    exportInfo.fileNamePrefix = app.activeDocument.name; // filename body part
     }
 }

 function saveFile( docRef, fileNameBody, exportInfo)
 {
     docRef.bitsPerChannel = BitsPerChannelType.EIGHT;
          var saveFile = new File(pathToSave + fileNameBody + ".jpg");
     jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
     jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = exportInfo.icc;
     jpgSaveOptions.quality = exportInfo.jpegQuality;
     docRef.saveAs(saveFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
 }
```

I am using Photoshop CS 6 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Your script works fine for me - what are the t and i values when it fails?  Make sure t-i is 0 or greater.

Comment: Are you using a MAC. I solved the issue by replacing app.activeDocument to activeDocument. Im using windows 7.

Comment: I'm on Win7 as well.  app.activeDocument and activeDocument refer to the same object.  app is just implied in the later.

Comment: okay I changed the above and changed my layers. Under the 8 layers i had an empty layer (layer 9). Then it worked it may have been because the empty layer was missing.

Comment: Yes, that would cause it - your script assumes some additional layers with the line 'var a = 1; // number base layers' so I had an extra one in my test document.

Comment: Thanks Anna Forest. :D